# Problems with string comparing with pointer

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have three lists and I want to implement a search feature.

How the code works is that I create an iterator that begins at the start of each list and it compares what the user inputs with each and every value in the list, when it finds a match it is supposed to increase an integer variable by one, so in the end it would say:

> `your value is found: <x amount of times in Example list>`

The problem I am having is that it is compiling fine but the end result still gives me 0 like it didn't increment the variable.

I am wondering if it is having trouble comparing the value where the iterator is pointing to the user input, can anyone please shed some light on this? For testing purposes in the

On the iterator `search_disregard` I manually put 4 identical values in the list, so I know the end result should show me 4, but I still get 0:

```
cout << "\nSearch for: ";
string edit_search;
cin >> edit_search;

list<string>::iterator search_disregard = disregard_list.begin();
list<string>::iterator search_compare   = compare_list.begin();
int search_disregard_count = 0;
int search_compare_count   = 0;


for (int x = 0; x < disregard_list.size(); ++x)
{
    if (*search_disregard == edit_search)
    {
        ++search_disregard_count;
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < compare_list.size(); ++x)
{
    if (*search_compare == edit_search)
    {
        ++search_compare_count;
    }
}

cout << edit_tag << edit_search << " is found in the following: \n" << endl;
cout << search_disregard_count << " time(s) in the Disregard List" << endl;
cout << search_compare_count << " time(s) in the Compare List" << endl;

buffer_clear();
```

Comment: You're compare the same string (the first one from each list) repeatedly to the test value in each loop. I.e. you never advance the iterators in either loop.

Comment: That is so true, wow. I feel like an idiot I have been coding too long today. Thank you for that really simple fix.

Answer (score 3):

You never increment your iterators so they will always point to the first element. The idiomatic way:

```
for(auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it) ...
```